# Java11 SetComponentMixingCutoutShapte alternative

Tags: java-8, deprecated, java-11, mixing

I have an application written on Java SE 8 that was heavily using features for mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight components.
In particular, the function "SetComponentMixingCutoutShape" was used, which was later deprecated in future versions of Java.

Now I have an option to switch to Java 11 - and I run into a problem. Seemingly, there's simply no alternative for this functionality in later versions of Java. Or at least I couldn't find one.
So what does that mean - that I simply don't have access to that feature AT ALL anymore?

Thanks for replies!

Comment: use the [official API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#setMixingCutoutShape(java.awt.Shape)) as a starting point. Or be more specific about “and I run into a problem”.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I asked I found the answer.

The functionality has been moved to component class

Before you used to call **setComponentMinxngCutoutShape(component, shape);**

Now you need to go **component.setMixingCutoutShape(shape);**